# I need a nonsense detector on my model

Tags: regression, social-science

So I'm trying to check internet availability's effect on terrorism. I was just going to run a regression of

> Number_of_Attacks ~ %access_of_internet + region(categorical)

To code %access_of_internet, I would code each attack with the proportional access of internet in that country in that year.

From this, I would interpret the coefficient to say that for every change in access to internet, the number of attacks will change by Y. Theoretically, I would make some argument about the strategic value of the internet. If the coefficient is positive, I could say something about how the internet broadens networks of terrorists and facilitates planning. If it is negative, I will say something about how the internet, contrary to popular belief, just makes it easier to catch terrorists due to a data trail.

Is this sound? If not, how would you suggest I fix it to answer the question: "does the internet facilitate terrorism?"

Comment: Sounds like nonsense to me. Internet access is one of many possible source of radicalization, and access to the internet won't cause radicalization in the absence of other additional causes (*you* have internet access but are unlikely a terrorist). But it's certainly not the only cause, nor is it even necessary (pre-Internet terrorism being the obvious example). So your model is incorrectly specified, which means you lose most of the desirable qualities of the coefficient estimates.

Comment: So why would the coefficients be significant and robust? I understand your point, but then why would there be robust coefficients? Just randomly?

Comment: Lots of incorrectly-specified models have significant and robust coefficients. Setting aside any numerical questions, just think through what you're saying: people who can access the internet carry out terrorist attacks. That's insane. Can you think of at least one other reason people carry out terrorist attacks, other than having access to the internet? Cf. omitted variable bias.

Comment: Well I'm not making a claim about if individual access to internet will make them more likely to cause terrorism. The access variable is a proxy for "internet infrastructure." Presumably places where more people use the internet, their internet services are superior. So the extrapolation is whether a good internet infrastructure makes it easier for terrorists groups to carry out attacks

Comment: What about internet access meaning access to more information, which could be an eye-opener for potential terrorists. What if this information make them less determined that bombing people is a good idea? What if internet access dilutes the influence of other sources of information, where those other sources are much more likely to support terrorism (e.g. meetings of local terrorists as an information source)?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. If the question is how do I ensure that my model makes sense, that is science and substance, not statistics. Otherwise put, you are, or should be, one nonsense detector and the same applies to your readers. @C11H17N2O2SNa is making more or less the same point by challenging your model; I agree with his main argument (I'd prefer not to use the word "insane" in discussion).

Comment: The relationship between *general* access to the internet and *an individual's* access is tenuous. People can rarely or never use the internet even in places with high potential access, and vice versa. To do a clean analysis, you'd need *at least* to measure each *individual*'s internet consumption. [This may be helpful.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecological_fallacy)

Comment: Specifically, there is likely to be a real difficulty with scale here. Many terrorist acts come down to individual or small-group decisions and actions, whereas (correct me if wrong) data on internet access are typically at national level. Naturally, I know that the data you need most just are not available but I don't agree with any premiss that a bad statistical model is better than none at all.

Comment: I'd go one step farther than @NickCox and say that a bad statistical model is *worse* than no model at all because models give the appearance of scientific validity to unscientific claims -- sometimes with catastrophic results when the models are poorly informed, invalid, etc. Andrew Wakefield's outright fraud and the econometric models which precipitated the recent economic crash being two prominent examples of how bad science can lead to bad outcomes.

Comment: @C11H17N2O2SNa Yes, broadly agreed. That's often the case (not quite invariably, as sometimes people can suggest ways to improve bad models, and bad models can make an argument or attitude explicit, which is itself likely to make discussion or debate easier).

Comment: Hmm. So I suppose its impossible to test if the internet actually does help terrorists?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is now purely qualitative. Determining whether terrorists are using the Internet to communicate ('facilitation') is a matter of picking some recent attacks that are of interest, and reading about the perpetrators' activities. But I think it's decidedly the case that the internet plays a role -- from C&C to propaganda to recruiting to radicalization to financing -- at every level...

Comment: @Hutchins It's not impossible, it's just going to involve many, many more steps of research and data collection to make any meaningful claims: you'll need to do a lot of work to address mutual causality, the ecological fallacy, and omitted variable bias, which is not going to be easy that the nation-state level.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a qualitative question. Or at the least, I'm not convinced we have closed the issue. I just found this paper, and I'm reading it now to see the methodology. http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/09636412.2014.905353?journalCode=fsst20#.VxjgXfkrKUk

Comment: What is a "nonsense detector"? If the topic just means "does this model make sense", perhaps it could be edited to be more informative about the question